# Why null string is not a string object

Tags: c#, string

Consider this code:

```
  class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                string s = null; 
                bool b = s is string;
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
        }
```

In above code `s is string` but b is `false`.

actually s as string,Why i get this result ?

Why compiler has this behavior?

Comment: `s` is not a string, it's a null reference. If it referred to something, that something would be a string.

Comment: however 'bool b = typeof(s) is string;' would yield the expected result

Comment: no i dont get null refrence

Comment: Let me ask back a helper question: what's the class of the `null` ?

Comment: Read [What the meaning of is is](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/) by Eric Lippert :)

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: There is a difference between `is` in the english language and `is` in the C# programming language.

Comment: @DaveShaw yesssssssss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When evaluating your statement, the runtime must first **follow** the reference to which the variable refers. Only then may it evaluate the referenced object to determine if it is indeed a string.

Since a `null` reference refers to no object, it is not a string. In fact, it is nothing at all.

You can use the `typeof` operator to get the `Type` object that corresponds to string, rather than compare a referenced object, if that's your ultimate goal.

This is actually the particular example given by Eric Lippert in a blog post on this very subject:

> I've noticed that the is operator is inconsistent in C#. Check this out:
>
> ```
> string s = null; // Clearly null is a legal value of type string
> bool b = s is string; // But b is false!
> ```
>
> What's up with that?

-- http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/

Comment: I'm not seeing how the `typeof` operator would be of any help in this situation.

Comment: @m-y If the OP is looking for the `Type` object of string, he can use `typeof` instead of the `is` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `s` is a reference that can potentially point to the location of a string in memory, however you haven't pointed it at a string yet - it points to 'null'. When you ask `s is string` you are saying 'does the reference `s` point to the location of a string in memory' and in your case the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

> The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that **does not refer to any object**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx

`s is string` is false because `s` does not reference an instance of `string` - `s` is null.